# Is an = equal to space when executing from terminal/Crontab?

Tags: terminal, cron, arguments

I just found a curious case, where crontab on two instances uses '=' or ' ' for value attribution.

Which of the following executions is correct (or both)?

Option 1
dosomething --parameter=x

Option 2
dosomething --parameter x

If that is not the correct question, what other factors should I take into consideration to know which one is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is just a scheduler. The syntax for passing arguments to `dosomething` is completely dependent on `dosomething`'s implementation. Some programs use a notation with space, some with `=` and some may use both.